# How to download VODs concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following code and it successfully downloads whatever list of YouTube URLs I have:

```
import os, pytube


youtube_URLs = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPlGWKm-jdg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPWFSCWJL_0']

current_dir = os.getcwd()


def youtube(url_list):
    if not os.path.exists(current_dir + '/youtube_videos/'):
        os.mkdir(current_dir + '/youtube_videos/')

    for i in url_list:
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(i)
        video = youtube.streams.first()
        video.download(current_dir + '/youtube_videos/')
```

But as you can see, it downloads them sequentially and this isn't ideal. How can I make this process concurrent? If I have a list of 5 VOD URLs, how can I download all 5 at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading several videos at the same time using pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883967/downloading-several-videos-at-the-same-time-using-pytube)

Comment: @PApostol Not really. I know about threadding but I don't know how to apply that when using a 3rd party framework

Comment: ok, does my answer help? It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use `threading` to run downloads in parallel. A simple example:

```
import threading
import pytube
import os

class DownloadVid(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, url, download_dir):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.url = url
      self.download_dir = download_dir 

   def run(self):
      print('Downloading URL: ' + self.url)
      youtube = pytube.YouTube(self.url)
      video = youtube.streams.first()
      video.download(self.download_dir)


youtube_URLs = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPlGWKm-jdg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPWFSCWJL_0']

download_dir = os.getcwd() + '/youtube_videos/'

if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
    os.mkdir(download_dir )

for url in youtube_URLs:
    DownloadVid(url, download_dir).start()
```